# add resources to library created from project

Tags: java, android, resources, libraries

I have a next problem:
I want to get a library based on android project and to use it in another project as 'external' library

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is possible - my MainProblem: how can I add resources into library? The way Project Properties -> Android -> "As Library" adds only .class-files!

MySituation:

```
public class ClassForLibrary extends Activity{

      onCreate(){
         setContentView(R.layout.library_activity_layout);
      }

      method1(){
      }

      method2(){
      }
}
```

So, I want to have a library with two files: ClassForLibrary.class and library_activity_layout.xml

Next I want to add this library using Build Path...

and start application as

```
public class MainActivity extends ClassForLibrary {

    . . . . . . . . . . 

}
```

I've tried a lot of code constructions but the most closest situation is

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001.
```

`#0x7f030001` is my library_activity_layout.xml that i put manually into created library.

Сan anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access private library files in another application, unless the library itself exposes them. In your case, your library would need to create a function that lets the application replace the layout with it's own.   Something like:

```
public class ClassForLibrary extends Activity{

  onCreate(){
     setContentView(R.layout.library_activity_layout);
  }

  public overrideContentView(ViewGroup root){
      .... replace root view with the one passed in....
  }

  method1(){
  }

  method2(){
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! You peeped my code! )) That's what I'm doing (ok, a little more complicated). The problem was in overrided setContentView() when I wanted to inflate unexisted resource.

Comment: So, I'll try to create dynamic layout instead of static resource. Perhaps this is the only way. I'm really grateful to you advice. Thanx a lot!